# Prove $\mathbf{\det(I+xy^T+uv^T)}=(1+\mathbf{y^Tx})(1+\mathbf{v^Tu)-(x^Tv)(y^Tu)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> I am asked to prove
>
> $$\mathbf{\det(I+xy^T+uv^T)}=(1+\mathbf{y^Tx})(1+\mathbf{v^Tu)-(x^Tv)(y^Tu)}$$
>
> By first proving that
> $\mathbf{\det(I+xy^T)}=1+\mathbf{y^Tx}$, where $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are $n$ vector.

---

Assuming that $x\neq0$, we can find vectors $w_1, w_2, \cdots, w_{n-1}$ such that the matrix $Q$ defined by $$Q=[x,w_1,w_2,\cdots, w_{n-1}]$$ is nonsingular and $x=Qe_1$, where $e_1=(1,0,0,\cdots,0)^T$. If we define $$y^TQ=(z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_n),$$ then $$z_1=y^TQe_1=y^TQ(Q^{-1}x)=y^Tx,$$ and $$\det(I+xy^T)=\det(Q^{-1}(I+xy^T)Q)=\det(I+e_1y^TQ).$$

After here I am not quite sure how to close the argument and then go on to prove that $\mathbf{\det(I+xy^T+uv^T)}=(1+\mathbf{y^Tx})(1+\mathbf{v^Tu)-(x^Tv)(y^Tu)}$.

Answer (score 1):

With the same idea as in [the proof of the matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), one finds after a 'short' computation
$$
\pmatrix{I&0&0\\ y^T&1&0\\ v^T&0&1}
\pmatrix{I+xy^T+uv^T&x&u\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1}
\pmatrix{I&0&0\\ -y^T&1&0\\ -v^T&0&1}
=\pmatrix{I&x&u\\ 0&y^Tx+1&y^Tu\\ 0&v^Tx& v^Tu+1}.
$$
Note that this proof does not rely on any non-singularity condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First off, for any (compatible) matrices $A$ and $B$, we have $\det(I+AB) = \det(I+BA)$.
In your case, $A$, $B$ are just column vectors.